# CodeIgniter errors in PHP file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have searched and read but don't really understand the answers posted for the questions of `Undefined Index` and `Undefined Variable`. These are the errors I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: claim_number Filename: core/MY_Controller.php Line Number: 161
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: claim_number Filename: email/review_status_changed.php Line Number: 28

My questions is where do I add the database field `claim_number`? Right now it uses `claim_id` and when I change it to `claim_number` I get the errors above.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling this data from your database, you'd either want to change the field name to `claim_number` or rather,

set a new index `$your_var['claim_number'] = $your_var['clain_id']`

Currently, you're trying to access a value that doesn't exist, and from your description of the problem, it seems you're setting that index (`$your_var['claim_number']`) to a variable (`$claim_number`) which, when used will also return undefined.

Comment: OK, but what file do I add that to?

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code. Essentially, you need to set that variable before you use it. If you're pulling the data from the database, you could set that variable right after you gather the data from the database

Comment: Which file do you need to see?

Comment: I'd need to see where you create the variable, and where you use it.  If you're creating the variables from a database call, I'll need to see that.